# Command for renaming several variables

Tags: r, dplyr, rename

After reshaping my data, I have a large dataset with columnnames that look like this: 
`1_abc` `1_vwxyz` `2_abc` `2_vwxyz`

I would like to change my column names to look like this: `abc_1` `vwxyz_1` `abc_2` `vwxyz_2`

My code looks like this:

```
data <- tibble("1_abc" = c(1,2,3), "1_vwxyz" = c(10,11,12), 
"2_abc" = c(1,1,2),"2_vwxyz" = c(9,11,15))

data_renamed <- data %>%
rename_(.dots=setNames(names(.), paste(substr(names(.), start=3, stop=nchar(names(.))), 
                                         substr(names(.), start=1, stop=1))))
```

I get this error:

```
Error in parse(text = x) : <text>:1:2: unexpected input
1: 1_
     ^
```

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? Use dput()

Comment: May I ask why? I'd hazard a guess you can avoid having to do this.

Comment: @Joe: It would be great if you could tell me an alternative way to reshape my data that doesn't add numbers in front of each variable name (preferably using dplyr). I originally had two rows for each person that I needed to spread in order to compute the stability of the two ratings for each person. I did this using this code: data <- data_orig %>% 
  gather(variable, value, -(person:seq)) %>%
  unite(temp, seq, variable) %>%
  spread(temp, value)

Comment: Sounds like you could maybe have done `group_by` and `summarise` on your original data to get the stability. But I'm not too sure without seeing your original data. Anyway below is a solution to rename the colnames.

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution in base R. You first take the column names as a character vector, convert them to a list of two-element character vectors, reverse the order of each and put them back together with `_`.

```
ll <- strsplit(colnames(data), pattern = "_")

# apply across this list of character vectors to reverse the order and concatenate
ll1 <- lapply(ll, function(x) paste(rev(x), collapse = "_"))

# unlist and assign them to the new data frame
data_renamed <- data
colnames(data_renamed) <- unlist(ll1)

#  A tibble: 3 x 4
#   abc_1 vwxyz_1 abc_2 vwxyz_2
#   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1     1      10     1       9
# 2     2      11     1      11
# 3     3      12     2      15
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution. I had to do a small adjustment for your first line of code to make it work (delete "pattern ="): 

# correct names
ll <- strsplit(colnames(data), "_")

# apply across this list of character vectors to reverse the order and concatenate
ll1 <- lapply(ll, function(x) paste(rev(x), collapse = "_"))

# unlist and assign them to the new data frame
data_renamed <- data
colnames(data_renamed) <- unlist(ll1)

Comment: Welcome, glad you got it to work! Would you mind accepting the answer (if it has sufficiently helped?)